# Proof of $\angle$ sum of polygon.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, polygons, angle

First, I know this question might have been asked by several times, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162392/why-sum-of-interior-angles-in-convex-polygon-is-n-2-cdot-180), for an example.
Before someone may want to mark it as **dulplicate**, I would like to calrify what I want to ask.

Mainly, I am asking for a **rigorous** proof, or **why it is rigorous enough**?

Notes: I will be considering [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon).

Consider the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655209/is-this-a-polygon) by Misha Lavrov,

> What makes things worse is that people often work with polygons on a
>   somewhat intuitive level

I agree with this.

I definitely know that

$$Interior\space\angle\space sum\space of\space a\space N-sided\space polygon=(N-2)180^\circ$$ as every high school text shall states.

Most of the proofs which I have seen about the problem, has a similar idea as the accepted answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162392/why-sum-of-interior-angles-in-convex-polygon-is-n-2-cdot-180).

Main idea of the proof:

For a polygon, we will just select points to join segments, and then we can devide the polygon into several pieces, and by $\angle$ sum of $\triangle$, we can *find the $\angle$ sum of the polygon*.

This proof is very intuitive, but  I don't think it is rigorous enough, **as I wonder, can we still connect every vertex to the point, even for a extremely ugly concave polygon, to seperate the polygon, into several $\triangle$s, such that each of the interior $\angle$ of each of the $\triangle$s is in an interior $\angle$ of the polygon and won't be counted twice.** For an explaination and example for what I said right above, see below.

e.g.)

For a 'ugly' 23-sided polygon, which I drew *'randomly'*:[image]
As in the image above, I discovered a way to divide the polygon into 21 pieces of $\triangle$, while it sounds to be eligible. However, **I don't think this will certainly happen**, if the polygon is even more ugly. How to explicitly consider the case, when different $\triangle$ share a same interior $\angle$ in the proof?

Also, as I asked above, can we always find a way to devide it properly? (I think it is important to prove it)

I also considered the way in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766143/prove-that-the-sum-of-the-degrees-in-the-interior-angles-of-a-polygon-with-n-s).

For the induction part, asumming the $\angle$ sum formula for polygon is true for $N$-sided polygon. Then, consider any $N+1$-sided polygon, I used to think that we can select $2$ vertex which is saperate by one vertex in middle (can I present it more precisely?), join them together, and we form a $\triangle$ (Do we need to consider whether 'convex'[image] or 'concave'[image]?). Then we form a $N$-sided polygon, and by the induction hypothesis and $\angle$ sum of $\triangle$, we can prove the formula holds for $N+1$.

But, moreover, do we need to consider this case[image] and/or this case[image], when the remaining polygon might not be $N$-sided?

**TO SUM UP, How can we consider all possible cases and make a rigorous proof? Most importantly, I want a justification of the constructability**(I mean whether the graph is constructable/valid, not for the [Compass-and-straightedge construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction))**and generality of a graph, if there is a graph in the proof.**

Remember, as I said above, I am looking for a rigorous proof, **not an usual one**.

Thank you so much for your answer :)

NOTES:Does the ways in [this](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/interior%20angle.htm) help?

Comment: Why not use induction. Then all you have to do is to draw a diagonal to reduce to a polygon with few sides?

Comment: @almagest Can you explain what you think with a rigorous proof as an answer?

Comment: @almagest I had been considering induction also, but I cannot complete an rigorous proof, as stated above in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The key fact is that every simple polygon, not necessarily convex, can be decomposed into $n-2$ triangles by drawing $n-3$ diagonals. Then the sum of the interior angles of the polygon is equal to the sum of interior angles of all triangles, which is clearly $(n-2)\pi$.

The existence of triangulations for simple polygons follows by induction once we prove the existence of a diagonal.
For a proof, see Chapter 1 of [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9489.html) by Devadoss and O'Rourke. This chapter is freely available.
The picture below from that chapter that captures the gist of the proof:

[image]

See also [Diagonals: Feature Column from the AMS](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-diagonals1) by Malkevitch.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103253/find-a-segment-inside-a-polygon/1103318#1103318.

Comment: Sorry, I just can't find a link of the freely available chapter...

Comment: @TonyMa, see `Resources` in the book page.

Comment: oic, thanks, I will read it later.